# how to configure Application Server extension for app fabric

Tags: dll, appfabric

I am looking for dlls , which I read on google is in C:\Windows\System32\Application Server extension . I cannot see this folder on the machine where appfabric is installed.

CacheBaseLibrary.dll 
ClientLibrary.dll 
FabricCommon.dll

Any ideas, how to get this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on a 64-bit Windows installation? If so, you will find the assemblies under the following location:

C:\Windows\SysNative\AppFabric

You can read about this in the MSDN section titled: [Preparing the Cache Client Development Environment (Windows Server AppFabric Caching)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790876.aspx)

Comment: It is 64 bit, but I cannot find SysNative folder

Answer (score 1):

Those DLLs were used in the beta versions of AppFabric, when it was codenamed Velocity. In the release version of AppFabric they have been replaced by
`Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll`
`Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll`

You should find these in %SYSTEMDRIVE%\System32\AppFabric, or follow Drew's answer if you're on 64-bit.

Comment: Ah, great catch on the beta assembly names. Been using so long those names didn't even look foreign. :)